# R Shiny Reactivity/Observer with multiple input and an action button

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Working on a shiny app/dashboard for risk analysis, basically implementing [this](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/429733_d79bd30cd24b4ba78d14e62fdc7baa8b.html) in shiny but I am running into few issues with using the input values to simulate them and print an output. When I run the app

I get a warning below:

[image: warning]

The app works but my final output suppose to be the max value but I get NA
like below:

[image]

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(mc2d)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "EngSec Risk Analysis"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 3,
             box(width = NULL,
                 title = "Loss Event Frequency",

                 numericInput("loss_event_frequency_min", label = h5("loss event frequency minimum"), value = 2),

                 numericInput("loss_event_frequency_max", label = h5("loss event frequency maximum"), value = 9),

                 numericInput("loss_event_frequency_likely", label = h5("loss event frequency likley"), value = 4)
             ),
             box(width = NULL,
                 title = "Loss Magnitude",

                 numericInput("loss_magnitude_min", label = h5("loss magnitude minimum"), value = 1000),

                 numericInput("loss_magnitude_max", label = h5("loss magnitude maximum"), value = 9000),

                 numericInput("loss_magnitude_likley", label = h5("loss magnitude likley"), value = 4000)
             ),
             actionButton("sample", "Click To Run Simulation")
      ),
      column(width = 9,
             box(width = NULL, textOutput("max")),
             box(width = NULL ))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  confidence <- 4 # default in PERT
  number_of_runs <- 10000
  set.seed(88881111)
  LEF <- eventReactive(input$sample, { 
    rpert(number_of_runs, input$loss_event_frequency_min, input$loss_event_frequency_likely, input$loss_event_frequency_max, shape = confidence)               
  })

  LM <- eventReactive(input$sample, { 
    rpert(number_of_runs, input$loss_magnitude_min, input$loss_magnitude_likely, input$loss_magnitude_max, shape = confidence)               
  })
  annual_loss_exposure <- eventReactive(input$sample, { LEF() * LM()})
  ALE <- eventReactive(input$sample, { 
    sapply(LEF(), function(e) sum(rpert(e, input$loss_magnitude_min, input$loss_magnitude_likely, input$loss_magnitude_max, shape = confidence)))
  })
  max_loss <- eventReactive(input$sample, { max(ALE())})
  min_loss <- eventReactive(input$sample, { min(ALE())})
  output$max <- renderPrint({max_loss()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: One thing that stands out is a misspelling: `loss_magnitude_likley` in your `ui`

Comment: @Ben OMG!!!! this was it I spend all day working on this!! THANK YOU! Add this as an answer so I accept I guess